# PATCH call not updating field via API

Tags: python, api, patch

Have a function to update a field in Netbox via API. The same data works on the Django web interface so I know it's not that, just something in my script that I'm doing wrong.

```
def change_allocated_server_status(api_token="", limit="",jira_access=""):
    api_token_here = "Token " + api_token
    headers = {'Authorization': api_token_here}
    params = {'limit': limit}

    sites = "https://my-url.com/api/dcim/devices/?role=server-planned"
    session = requests.Session()
    site_response = session.get(sites, headers=headers, params=params)
    site_results = site_response.json()['results']

    allocated_servers = get_devices_by_dc_loca(api_token, limit, jira_access)

    url = "https://my-url.com/api/dcim/devices/239"


    update = {
            "device_role": 41
    }

    change = requests.patch(url, headers=headers, data=update)
    change_results = change.json()
    print change_results
```

The output of *print change_results* is

```
{u'status': 2, u'device_role': 40, u'name': u'device-name', u'site': 1, u'comments': u'', u'rack': 4, u'asset_tag': None, u'platform': None, u'primary_ip4': None, u'device_type': 7, u'primary_ip6': None, u'custom_fields': {}, u'position': 5, u'serial': u'', u'face': 0, u'id': 239, u'tenant': 1}
```

device_role isn't being changed. Doing a *print change.status_code* returns 200 so I know I'm hitting the API without a authentication problem, just guessing it's something simple I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was missing a '/' from the end of my url, stopping the PATCH from being called but throwing no error.